# angular 2 RC5: platform-browser.umd.js:937 EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise):

Tags: angular, angular-rc5

I'm using service to make a request.

**homepage.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Http, Response } from "@angular/http";

import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import { PATH } from "../const/config";

import { SliderRequest } from "../request/slider.request";

@Injectable()

export class HomepageService {
    private sliderUrl = PATH.url.getUrl();
    constructor (private _http: Http) {}
    getSlider(): Observable<SliderRequest> {
        let doRequest = this._http.get(this.sliderUrl.slider).map(
            (res) => {
                let response = res.json();
                return response;
            }
        );
        return doRequest;
    }
}
```

And I use this service into homepage component

**homepage.component.ts**

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { CONFIG, PATH } from "../../const/config";

import { Inject } from "../../inject/inject";

// import service
import { HomepageService } from "../../services/homepage.service";

@Component({
    selector: 'app-home',
    templateUrl: CONFIG.baseUrlForComponentView("home"),
    providers: [HomepageService]
})

export class HomeComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnInit {
    private sliders: any[];
    private shortDescription: any[];
    constructor( private homeService:  HomepageService) {}
    ngOnInit() {
        let that = this;
        this.homeService.getSlider().subscribe(
            (response) => {
                var data = response.data;
                this.shortDescription = data.shortDescription.text;
            }
        );
    }
    ngAfterViewInit() {
        Inject.load(PATH.javascript, 'global')
    }
}
```

And into my template I do this:

```
{{shortDescription.description}}
```

And it return the error bellow:

```
platform-browser.umd.js:937 EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): EXCEPTION: Error in public/templates/view/home.tpl.html:0:0
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'description' of undefined
ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'description' of undefined
```

So I try this:

```
{{shortDescription | debug}}
```

debug is a special pipe that I create to ensure that it returns value, and It return the value bellow:

```
"shortDescription": {
            "video": {
                "url": ""
            },
            "text": {
                "description": "<strong>Lorem</strong>ipsum",
                "goTo": "le concept"
            }
        }
```

But if I try to use `description` property or `goTo` property, it returns the error I mentionned before.

And do not understand what happen with this?

All helps are welcomed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're getting data asynchronously at first time your variable `shortDescription` equals `undefined`.

[Elvis operator](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#safe-navigation-operator) should resolve your issue:

```
{{shortDescription?.description}}
```

*Other options*:

1) use structural directive **ngIf**:

```
<template *ngIf="shortDescription">
  {{shortDescription.description}}
</template>
```

2) set initial value

```
export class HomeComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnInit {
  private shortDescription = { description: '' };
  ...
```

Comment: So, what is the best way to do it, if I don't want to use the Elvis operators?
Now, It works, but is there another way to resolve this?